# Why a borwser can't connect with WebSocket server?

Tags: websocket

I wrote Websocket server. I think it returns everything good, by maybe I miss something.
This is what a browser send to it:

```
GET /app HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: pm.local:4444
Origin: http://pm.local
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Key: dkX2mQo3cBVA0DMQ7m9oTw==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: x-webkit-deflate-frame
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36
```

and the server send that reponse:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Origin: http://pm.local
Sec-WebSocket-Location: http://pm.local/app
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: KrfNVY/hsidqg2HX7YBdXHD/SQM=
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: sample
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://pm.local
```

Of course, on the end it always sends '\r\n'.

Do you know what is wrong with this response? 
Thanks for help

Comment: Include more information.  What happens on the browser side?  What happens on the server side?  Check the logs.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. On the browser side websocket object readyState has value 0. Also, the status of connection is "pending". I trying to write a WebSocket server, so I haven't any logs yet.

Answer (score 0):

The Sec-WebSocket-Location should be something like `ws://[host]/[uri]`, starting with "ws" instead of "http".

Comment: Please start a new question if you need assistance on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove Sec-WebSocket-Protocol header from response. It's invalid to include it when the client didn't send the header.

Please also remove Sec-WebSocket-Location header. It's old spec's stuff. Not used in RFC 6455.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help, but I found a "bug" in my code.
I wrote server in Java, and every line in response was ending by

```
'\r' + '\n'
```

But it should be

```
"\r\n"
```

And that's it. Now it works :)